# Great computer graphics for matter modelling

Tags: density-functional-theory, software, ab-initio-calculations, visualization-software, diffusion-monte-carlo

I am trying to write some code to automatically generate a judicious set of graphics from DFT/fn-DMC calculations so that users can sanity check their results quickly. My literature review has found that [volume rendering](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/616024.617765) of the wavefunctions is a good first choice, then isosurfaces of constant $|\psi|^2$, and Fermi surfaces where appropriate.

However, many of these visualization routines are computationally cheap, relative to the simulations, so the more ways to understand the simulation data, the merrier.

- **What are the awesome graphics you have seen in published literature that gave you unique insight into a quantum system?**
- **What graphics should be co-produced with each simulation to make life easier for matter modelling practitioners?**

Just to get things started:

[Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.07680) is a paper with nice graphics (see Figure 5); it looks to my untrained eye like they are creating "widened Fermi surfaces" similar to the result of ARPES measurements.

[image]

[2D systems](http://www.condmat.physics.manchester.ac.uk/pdf/mesoscopic/publications/graphene/RMP_2009.pdf) (e.g. Figure 3) allow some more interesting band structure visualizations; although I imagine this is possible in 3D if we slice through a lattice plane.

[image]

Plotting the unit cell is an obvious choice, since many of these programs require hand-typed input decks. This won't give any unique insight, but it would be a good sanity check.

[This paper](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/365/6459/1278/tab-pdf) is chock-full of killer graphics; I especially enjoy the Berry curvature field in figure 4c.

[image: Berry Curvavture]

Comment: +1. It might be better suited as two separate questions: "what are some awesome graphics" and "what graphics should be co-produced with each simulation". They seem to be rather different questions and we [need more questions anyway](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/165/5).

Comment: I liked your questions, but I'm afraid that the first one is very personal as "awesome" is related with fillings. About the second one, instead of "what graphics", I think that "what properties" could be better. Of course, the latter will strongly dependent on the code you are focuses as each one has its own format.

Answer (score 9):

## Magnetic Anisotropy

The best way to understand magnetic anisotropy is to visualize it. I think a visualization should be co-produced with every calculation of magnetic anisotropic energy.

The following [figure](https://hal-univ-rennes1.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01381124/document) shows Magnetocrystalline anisotropy energy calculated for G-type antiferromagnetic LiNbO3-type InFeO3$^1$. [image]

Another [figure](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms3511.pdf?origin=ppub) shows MAE of CuO calculated for the GS AF1 magnetic structure$^2$
[image]

**References**

1. Fujita, Koji, et al. "LiNbO3-type InFeO3: room-temperature polar magnet without second-order Jahn–Teller active ions." Chemistry of Materials 28.18 (2016): 6644-6655.
2. Rocquefelte, Xavier, et al. "Room-temperature spin-spiral multiferroicity in high-pressure cupric oxide." Nature Communications 4.1 (2013): 1-7.